# Spring Cloud Gateway: How to configure a route to Consul UI?

Tags: java, spring, consul, spring-cloud-gateway

I try to configure spring cloud gateway to forward to the standard ui of HashiCorp Consul under '/consul/ui' or just '/consul'. I however don't get how to do that correctly. Consul is running in standard configuration. I have an external ip address and a local network interface on 10.2.0.2. I tried:

```
routes:
    - id: consul
      uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8500"
      predicates:
        - Path=/consul/
```

curl -L 127.0.0.1/consul/ui however gives me a 500, since according to the logs the gateway doesn't match /consul but /consul/** and then decides to route to 10.2.0.2:8300 which is Consuls rpc endpoint.

Another try:

```
- id: consul
      uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8500"
      predicates:
      - Path=/consul/**
      filters:
      - StripPrefix=1
```

... did exactly the same as the other one.
Another promising approach:

```
- id: consul
      uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8500"
      predicates:
      - Path=/consul/**
      filters:
      - RewritePath=/consul/(?<segment>.*), /ui/$\{segment}
```

Using curl -L actually works on the command line. However, in a browser I only see the consul logo, but the whole page doesn't load.

I've of course also tried some other combinations, none worked.

Note: The consul /ui endpoint delivers a status 302 and then forwards to the actual page.

Note: I use SSL in the gateway.

Note: `ssh -N -f -L 8500:localhost:8500 <user>@<host>` allows me to open the expected ui locally under localhost:8500.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently `/consul/**` was a bad choice since consul itself is already registered under this route, thus I had a conflict. This at least makes clear, why cloud gateway tried routing to port 8300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at present there is no real answer to this question, but some hacky workarounds. However, folks are working on a solution to be able to proxy pass consul ui. See e.g. https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/1382